# SQL Query to form duo pairs

Tags: sql

I have a table with three fields id, name and no. of years. I need to form a table of duos of last names based on the condition if no. of years of a person is greater than the other, they should form a pair. I tried the following query. But it returns no rows. Why?

```
select s1.LastName as "coach",s2.LastName as "Trainee" 
from Members s1 
     join Members s2 on s1.SID=s2.SID 
where s1.Years>s2.Years;
```

```
SID Name Years
1   Leo   4
2   Aldrin 1
3   Niks  5
4   Smith 1
```

```
Output
Leo  Aldrin
Leo  Smith
Niks Leo
Niks Aldrin
Niks Smith
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags, pls add the one back that you actually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an *inequality* on the check on `SID`:

```
SELECT
    s1.LastName AS "coach",
    s2.LastName AS "Trainee"
FROM Members s1
INNER JOIN Members s2
    ON s1.SID <> s2.SID AND   -- this is maybe not even necessary here, by the way
       s1.Years > s2.Years;
```

The above query says to find all coach/trainee pairs, being defined as the former having more years than the latter.  The reason your initial query was not returning any records is that only one record will have a given `SID` identifier, and by definition its `Years` value will also be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cross join` to do that:

```
SELECT
    s1.LastName AS "coach",
    s2.LastName AS "Trainee"
FROM Members s1, Members s2
WHERE s1.SID <> s2.SID AND s1.Years > s2.Years;
```